# Event Emitter is not working in callback

Tags: node.js, express

I try to run this code, everything goes well but event emitter is not working . I just want to check from the router that data is duplicate or saved .

database.js

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var auths = require('../model/hiren-conf');
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

var ee = new EventEmitter();

exports.create = function(req){
    var instance = new auths.auth();
    if(req.body.tag && req.body.email){
        auths.auth.findOne({ 'tag' : req.body.tag , 'email' : req.body.email}, function(err , duplicate){
            if (!err){
                if(!duplicate){
                    instance.tag = req.body.tag;
                    instance.email = req.body.email;
                    instance.save(function(err){
                        if(!err) console.log('Saved');

                    });
                    ee.emit('Save');

            }       else {
                    console.log("Duplicate");
                    ee.emit('Duplicate');
                };
        } else console.log(err);
        });

        }

    };
```

routes/new.js

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();
var database = require('./database.js');
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

var ee = new EventEmitter();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('newdata', {
        title: 'Add new data'
    })
});

router.post('/', function(req, res){
     database.create(req);
    ee.on('Save', function(){
        console.log('data saved')
    });
    ee.on('Duplicate', function(){
        console.log('Duplicate data')
    });
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but currently the POST function registers two listeners that will output data on the console. Is that not working or did you want to do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating different ee object in two different files.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
     database.create(req, ee);//try passing the ee object and use it to emit the event in db.js
    ee.on('Save', function(){
        console.log('data saved')
    });
    ee.on('Duplicate', function(){
        console.log('Duplicate data')
    });
    res.end();
});
```